# Why would Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey return null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, registry

This line of code previously worked, but now returns null.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"MIME\Database\Content Type\" + mimeType, false);
```

Any ideas why this would be so?

Can I check it manually?

Comment: What did you change? Have you verified the key still exists?

Comment: You can check it manually by going to run and typing `regedit` and running that program

Comment: According to the documentation the return value is:

> The subkey requested, or null if the operation failed
> 
> If the requested key does not exist, this method returns null instead
> of throwing an exception.

Are you sure the key exist?

Comment: Looking at regedit, application/pdf exists, but pdf/application does not.